# SignOut is not working in Fragment using Item Menu with firebase

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-authentication, menuitem

This is my Profile fragment and I am having three of them in main Activity.
Here I am using Sign out functionality but it is not working.

```
package com.example.user.transroads;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

public static ProfileFragment newInstance() {
    ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
    return fragment;
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.item_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.signOut: 
            firebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
}
```

I want to log out from a fragment. I have three of them with bottom Navigation but the sign out is not happening it should be intent on the LogInActivity.

Please help me out solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I won't believe that signout is not working.It might be because android saves activities states.

As you are saying on clicking on signout you want to launch loginActivity.You can do this by removing all activities from back stack.

To do this use it.

```
case R.id.signOut: 
            firebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), 
            NewActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        return true;
```

OR

for **AlertDialog** you can create a method alertsignout() outside onCreate() like this :

```
public void alertsignout()
{
           AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new 
            AlertDialog.Builder(
            getActivity());

             // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog2.setTitle("Confirm SignOut");

            // Setting Dialog Message
             alertDialog2.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Signout?");

            // Setting Positive "Yes" Btn
             alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("YES",
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
           firebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
           Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), 
            NewActivity.class);
           i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
           Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
           startActivity(i);
        }
    });

              // Setting Negative "NO" Btn
            alertDialog2.setNegativeButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to execute after dialog
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

          // Showing Alert Dialog
          alertDialog2.show();


}
```

And call this method like this :

```
case R.id.signOut: 
            alertsignout();
        return true;
```

**PS** : I havn't tested it so if there are any error.. ask me

Comment: Thanx Sahdeep it works but can you please help me little more that i just want to add AlertDialog Builder on signOut.

Comment: Thanx but i have done it in onOptionsItemSelected() using your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line of code:

```
firebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

with

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```